# How to check the value of an input text and show correct or wrong

Tags: jquery, html

I'm making a simple maths question website to get better in jQuery and have come across a problem. It wont take the answer and only shows it as if it were wrong

my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const myForm = $('#MyForm');
  const ul = $('items')
  const userList = $('#users');
  const AnswerInput = $('#Answer1').val();
  const msg = $('.msg');

  myForm.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (AnswerInput === '' || AnswerInput != '(x+2)(x+3)') { // if empty or wrong
      msg
        .slideDown(2000)
        .delay(1000)
        .addClass('error')
        .text('Please Enter an Answer');
      msg.delay(2500).slideUp(2000);
      //setTimeout(()=> msg.slideUp(), 2000)
    } else if (AnswerInput === '(x+2)(x+3)') { // if right
      msg
        .slideDown(2000)
        .delay(1000)
        .addClass('Correct')
        .text('You are right');
      msg.delay(2500).slideUp(2000);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Maths</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/StyleSheet.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="msg"></div>
      <form id="MyForm">
        <label for="answer"> Factorise x<sup>2</sup> + 5x + 6:</label>
        <input type="text" id="Answer1" class="inputText">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn" id="clickBtn">

      </form>
    </div>
    <ul id="users">
      <li>ghv</li>
      <li>jhbh</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!--<script src="Javascript/JavaScript.js"></script>-->
  <script src="Javascript/jQuery.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

It only shows the error function even if I put the right answer message

Comment: does using `!==` in the comparison `AnswerInput != '(x+2)(x+3)'` make a difference?

Comment: @jtylerm both values (on either side of the expression) are already strings so why would it make any difference? No, you missed the issue...see my answer below.

Comment: You're reading `AnswerInput` before the `submit` event fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move

```
const AnswerInput = $('#Answer1').val();
```

inside the

```
myForm.submit(function(e){
```

event handler.

What you're doing now is assigning to `AnswerInput` the value of the input box as it was when the page was first loaded. You then keep that variable's value the same for the lifetime of the page. You never attempt to read the value of the input box again after the user submits the form.

If you move that line inside the event handler function then it will read the latest value from the input box whenever the form is submitted.